# Aggregate Exception infinite loop

Tags: c#

I have a block of C# code that contains a try/catch when connecting a client to a server using SignalR. My issue is that if I try to handle `AggregateException` using Microsoft's example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx) I end up with an infinite loop of `AggregateException` being thrown and caught even though I am thinking they shouldn't be.

My code looks just like Microsofts:

```
Connection = new HubConnection(Url);
Hub = Connection.CreateHubProxy(HubProxy);
try
{
    Connection.Start().Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException aggEx)
{
    foreach (var e in aggEx.InnerExceptions)
    {
        if (e is SocketException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

What would cause this to happen?

Comment: Are you sure it's an infinite loop? Maybe you're debugging and there's nowhere that catches the rethrow. [This answer has details.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24962377)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - Infinite Loop at Exception Throwing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961208/c-sharp-infinite-loop-at-exception-throwing)

Answer (score 2):

You are not cacthing the exception throwed in cacth block. Visual Studio's default behaviour is to stop at the place where an unhandled exception would terminate the application.